# How to validate geometry in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

How can I validate the geometry in Openlayers?

I need to check  "**MULTILINESTRING()**" (which is empty) is valid/not valid. In postGIS, for Geometry validation we are using "**isValid()**" function. Like this, is there any options in Openlayers?

Comment: How are you getting/building the Geometry? From User interaction? or From GeoJSON/WKT? or something else?

Comment: From user interaction

Comment: Please provide more information on how you are getting the geometry from the user. Please see this post on how you could improve this question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question

Answer (score 4):

In OpenLayers you can't but you can use the excellent [JavaScript Topology Suite](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) (a Javascript rewrite of the Java Topology Suite).

Example:

```
  var reader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
  var geom = reader.read('POLYGON ((80 300, 280 300, 280 80, 80 80, 80 300), (260 280, 180 200, 100 280, 100 100, 260 100, 260 280))');        
  console.log(geom.isValid());
```

Comment: do you know how to handle errors thrown if it's not a valid Polygon?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using geodata through some form of GeoJson I can recommend this link;

http://geojsonlint.com/

It has an API that you can use as well, both python and javascript are explained on the website. With the api you are able to post a geojson and it will reply with a request status.